# system.drawing reference

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to set the backColor of a text box like this:

```
txtCompanyName.BackColor = Drawing.Color.WhiteSmoke;
```

It doesn't like it because it wants me to add System in front like:

```
txtCompanyName.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.WhiteSmoke;
```

Now that works, but it irritates me that I have to type System.  I'm referencing System at the top of my code with using System;   Shouldn't that do the trick so I don't have to type System in front of drawing, not sure why I still have to type System, anybody know?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9433012/why-cant-i-write-io-directory-getfiles

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C# you can't specify a type name by means of a partial namespace.  In C# the name must either be

- A fully qualified name including the entire namespace or namespace alias
- A type name only

The `Drawing` portion of `Drawing.Color.WhiteSmoke` is a non-fully qualified namespace and hence illegal as a type name.  You either need to add the prefix `System` or add a `using System.Drawing` and change the type name to `Color.WhiteSmoke`

Alternatively you can create an alias for the `System.Drawing` namespace named `Drawing`.

```
using Drawing = System.Drawing;
```

It is legal to use the alias as the start of a type name in C#.

Answer (score 1):

Easily fixed:

```
using Drawing = System.Drawing;

...

txtCompanyName.BackColor = Drawing.Color.WhiteSmoke;
```

Answer (score 1):

The using statement is importing the types that are in the specified namespace; this does not include child namespaces.

If you really wanted, you could use the following line:

```
using Drawing = System.Drawing;
```

which would allow you to refer to the System.Drawing namespace as 'Drawing'. This is probably not the best solution though. Really you should just use:

```
using System.Drawing;
```

your line then becomes:

```
txtCompanyName.BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
```

if you need to disambiguate between System.Drawing.Color and some other Color class (like Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color) you can use lines like this:

```
using XNAColor = Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color;
using WinColor = System.Drawing.Color;
```

then your line is:

```
txtCompanyName.BackColor = WinColor.WhiteSmoke;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using system, but you aren't using System.Drawing. Add `using System.Drawing;` to the rest of your using statements.

Comment: That's not the problem here.  In C# you can't using a name which begins with a partial namespace.